# Valuation of chooser options

Tags: options, valuation

The below formula for valuation of chooser options from Hull's book is not making sense to me.

[image]

Why do we use call value at time T=0 while we use put value using t=0 call value and discount strike and stock price to T=1?

Comment: He’s using the put call parity. $C+K = P + S$

Comment: You consider the chooser’s value at time $t=T_1$. That’s when you choose whether you want a call or put. The two options $c$ and $p$ expire at time $T_2$. That’s why the two exponentials have $T_2-T_1$ in the exponent when you apply the put-call parity. The chooser value is a call option with maturity $T_2$ plus $e^{-q(T_2-T_1)}$ times a put option with maturity $T_1$ and adjusted strike.